# SQL query based on a column in parent table - Parent child relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following three TABLES(ACCOUNTS,CUSTOMER,EMPLOYEE) and I would like to join them based on the columns AGENT_CODE & AGENT_TYPE and achieve the below.

What should be the best way to join these tables when AGENT_CODE can be same in CUSTOMER & EMPLOYEE table?

I have this query which is giving me wrong results

```
 SELECT ac.AGENT_CODE,
 ac.WORKING_AREA,
 ac.AGENT_TYPE,
 CONCAT(c.FIRST_NAME,c.LASTNAME_NAME),
 e.EMP_NAME
FROM ACCOUNTS ac,
CUSTOMER c,
EMPLOYEE e 
WHERE ac.AGENT_CODE = e.AGENT_CODE 
OR ac.AGENT_CODE = c.AGENT_CODE
```

GETTING_WRONG_RESULTS_WITH_THE_ABOVE_QUERY

```
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| AGENT_CODE | WORKING_AREA       | AGENT_TYPE | CUSTOMER_NAME| EMP_NAME     |
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| A007       | Bangalore          |   CUSTOMER |Walter Holmes |Walter Holmes | 
| A007       | London             |   EMPLOYEE |Walter Holmes |Peter Sam     |
| A008       | New York           |   CUSTOMER |Micheal Junior|Micheal Junior| 
| A007       | Bangalore          |   EMPLOYEE |Walter Holmes |John Tyler    | 
| A010       | Chennai            |   CUSTOMER |Micheal       |Micheal       | 
| A007       | San Jose           |   EMPLOYEE |Walter Holmes |Albert        | 
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**Expecting Result**

```
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+
| AGENT_CODE | WORKING_AREA       | AGENT_TYPE | AGENT_NAME   |
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+
| A007       | Bangalore          |   CUSTOMER |Walter Holmes | 
| A003       | London             |   EMPLOYEE |Peter Sam     |
| A008       | New York           |   CUSTOMER |Micheal Junior| 
| A011       | Bangalore          |   EMPLOYEE |John Tyler    | 
| A010       | Chennai            |   CUSTOMER |Micheal       | 
| A012       | San Jose           |   EMPLOYEE |Albert        | 
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+
```

**ACCOUNTS(AGENT_CODE -PrimaryKey)**

```
+------------+--------------------+------------+
| AGENT_CODE | WORKING_AREA       | AGENT_TYPE |
+------------+--------------------+------------+
| A007       | Bangalore          |   CUSTOMER |
| A003       | London             |   EMPLOYEE |
| A008       | New York           |   CUSTOMER |
| A011       | Bangalore          |   EMPLOYEE |
| A010       | Chennai            |   CUSTOMER |
| A012       | San Jose           |   EMPLOYEE |
| A005       | Brisban            |   EMPLOYEE |
+------------+--------------------+------------+
```

**CUSTOMER(AGENT_CODE -ForeignKey)**

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+  
|CUST_CODE  | FIRST_NAME   | LAST_NAME  | AGENT_CODE |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| C00013    | Walter      | Holmes      | A007      |
| C00001    | Micheal     | Junior      | A008       |
| C00020    | Albert      | Skyler      | A010       |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

**EMPLOYEES(AGENT_CODE -ForeignKey)**

```
EMP_NAME    EMP_CODE       AGENT_CODE 
----------  --------------- ----------
Peter Sam    C00054          A003
John Tyler   C00023          A011
White Bolt   C00043          A012
```

Comment: @Eric - added my current query

Comment: please add your current (incorrect) results too

Comment: @MarshallTigerus -added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine the result, you may want to `UNION` your result.

```
SELECT a.AGENT_CODE, a.WORKING_AREA, a.AGENT_TYPE, c.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || c.LAST_NAME AS AGENT_NAME
FROM ACCOUNTS a
JOIN CUSTOMER c ON c.AGENT_CODE = a.AGENT_CODE
UNION
SELECT a.AGENT_CODE, a.WORKING_AREA, a.AGENT_TYPE, e.EMP_NAME
FROM ACCOUNTS a
JOIN CUSTOMER e ON e.AGENT_CODE = a.AGENT_CODE
```